# Using Virtualbox on a Windows host, how can I route all traffic from a specific guest through TOR without changes to the guest?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, tor

I have Virtualbox and TOR already installed on a Windows host.  How can I have a virtual machine's network always go through TOR without installing TOR or configuring anything within the guest OS?  Virtualbox has an option to set a proxy but this doesn't route any traffic from guest VMs through it.  Basically I want the guest VM to be unaware of the local host network and TOR itself while all of its traffic goes through TOR.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need an tunnel adapter for Tor. I have not seen many tor clients, but those I have seen just set up TOR for one application. A Tun adapter will let you use routing rules to encapsulate any traffic into TOR.
2. You need to share the tun device. You should be able to find guides online on how to share a VPN connection with other machines on a LAN. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445166/share-a-vpn-connection-over-wifi) seems like a start, but requires some adaptation to pass the entire internet through the tun. Use 0.0.0.0/0 instead of 192.168.0.0/24 in various places.

It seems there are some tools out there that help combine both steps. [BadVPN](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn/wiki/Tun2socks) came up on google.